# Probability Question Rationale Threw Me - Double Probability of Winning a Single Game

Tags: probability

I was given the question:

> James plays $2$ games of tennis against his friend Shaun. For each game the probability of James winning is $0.3$

The games are independent. James thinks he is more likely to win at least one game than not. Is he right?

The rationale explained:

This is what you get when you double the probability of James winning a single game:

My question in trying to understand their rationale was:
Are you actually doubling the probability of him winning a single game by virtue of the fact that the statement *The games are independent* exists?

The worked solution then goes on to say *The probability of winning one game or more is the probability of winning both games plus the probability of winning the first OR second game*.

i.e.

$0.3×0.3 = 0.09+2(0.3 ×0.7) = 0.42$

$= 0.51$

Therefore it is greater than half.

Comment: Don't write things like $.3\times .3=.09+2(.3\times .7)=.42$....it's very confusing.

Comment: That said, your calculation looks sound.  Another way to see it is that the probability that James loses both games is $.7^2=.49$, so the probability he wins at least one is $1-.49=.51$   As you remark, the quote you provide is too terse and obscure to derive much meaning from.